boxplot scaling
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={PT,RP-T,P-T},
    % xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a},
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=-0.052077,
      upper quartile=1.627744,
      lower quartile=-1.613357,
      upper whisker=9.878565,
      lower whisker=-8.484539
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.893359,
      upper quartile=32.047894,
      lower quartile=-29.725945,
      upper whisker=219.879028,
      lower whisker=-242.360413
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=357.228912,
      upper quartile=32866.879883,
      lower quartile=-31571.360840,
      upper whisker=149471.640625,
      lower whisker=-147415.8125
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I want to show you well for each data range, but the gap between each data range is so large that the two boxplots look just solid.
I tried to reduce the data range and replace it with exponential notation on the scale, but it was awkward because the range of graphs to be expressed is narrow.
Is there a good way for me?

Welcome. // Please make your code compile, e.g. add at least the relevant preamble. Thank you

Thanks for the update. However, it still can‘t compile when we copy it … Please add what‘s missing, i.e. copy your posted code into a new file and compile. Do you see it? Thank you

@MS-SPO Thanks for your advice! Finally, I fixed it the code can compile.

Thank you :) // It's a problem of presentation, indeed. May I ask, what these data present? Besides indicating the distributions, why do you use a boxplot?

Because you can't switch to logarithmic scale here, I suggest to do some kind of split drawing, like shown below. Remarks:

copied your monolithic axis into 3 individual ones
put each insied a scope, e.g. for placement
assigned a width and height to each
put some lines/arrows to indicate some kind of magnification

There are some tasks left to do for a nice picture:

select better min/max values, so all "0"s will be aligned center
find a way to assign global names to each scope to simplify drawing, e.g. like \draw (A.south) -- (B.north west); , where (A) is the first, and (B) the second scope

Final suggestion: Create this drawing in a standalone class AND use package graphicx to include said pdf as image in your documentclass of choice.

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},
    ind/.style={->, teal!50},
]
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{scope}
  \begin{axis}
    [
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={PT},
        % xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a},
        height=4cm, width=10cm,
    ]
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
          median=357.228912,
          upper quartile=32866.879883,
          lower quartile=-31571.360840,
          upper whisker=149471.640625,
          lower whisker=-147415.8125
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis} 
 \end{scope}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
  \begin{axis}
    [
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={RP-T},
        % xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a},
        height=4cm, width=10cm,
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.893359,
      upper quartile=32.047894,
      lower quartile=-29.725945,
      upper whisker=219.879028,
      lower whisker=-242.360413
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis} 
 \end{scope}
 
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm]
  \begin{axis}
    [
        ytick={1},
        yticklabels={P-T},
        % xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,a},
        height=4cm, width=10cm,
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=-0.052077,
      upper quartile=1.627744,
      lower quartile=-1.613357,
      upper whisker=9.878565,
      lower whisker=-8.484539
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis} 
 \end{scope}
  
  % ~~~ drawing some lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[ind] (4.2,- .5) -- (0,-1.5);
  \draw[ind] (4.2,-4.5) -- (0,-5.5);
  
  \draw[ind] (4.3,- .5) -- (8.5,-1.5);
  \draw[ind] (4.5,-4.5) -- (8.5,-5.5);
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

